# “Friday I am in love” or “On Friday I am in love”?

Tags: time, adverbial-phrases

The question itself is wider. If I am not mistaken, putting “Friday” in the song title by the Cure means “On Friday”. Can we use it everyday and not only with days of the week but other time markers, like “February, she is gone to Australia”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That song's lyrics go:

> (It's) Friday, (and) I'm in love.

In spoken English, prepositions or function words can get mumbled/dropped when their exact details don't matter.

> (In/By/For) February, I'll be in Australia

All 3 options would mostly imply the same thing, so when speaking english casually, they can generally be omitted.

Comment: “In spoken english, leading prepositions can sort of get mumbled/dropped when their exact details don't matter.” True! But none of these are prepositions.  If you rephrase this with the term *function words*, a larger class that includes these words as well as prepositions, I can add my upvote.  For further research look up *left-edge deletion* or *conversational deletion* and compare *diary drop*.

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. Punctuation is very important. "Hello, Mary. It's Helen. I'm in love with another one". My mistake.